# A very stubborn "returning view versus a copy" problem

Tags: pandas

`raw_df.loc[:,'full_size'] = raw_df.loc[:,:].apply( full_size,axis="columns",).copy()`
is throwing the warning:

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

I thought/recalled that normally I can fix this by making sure everything is `.loc`'d properly, or making the the right hand side a `copy()`.   But this line has been stubbornly throwing the warning regardless.   Maybe I'm misunderstanding the warning, but I cannot see what I'm doing here that is potentially-dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is legit since you're calling [**`pandas.Series.copy`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.copy.html) on a series where in the same line you assign this one to another series.

I can't tell what's your needs but you can try this approach instead:

```
raw_df['full_size']= raw_df.apply(full_size, axis='columns')

ser_fullsize= raw_df.loc[:,'full_size'].copy() # or raw_df['full_size'].copy()
```